# why does Java servlet gives ClientAbortException when file size larger than about 2 MB?

Tags: java, servlets, ioexception, mod-jk

I'm trying to write a java servlet that is located on a Linux server, that may be used by a client to download a video file. It works when the file size is small (perhaps less than 2 MB), but larger file sizes return the error: `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe`.

After searching Google, it appears this error occurs when the client breaks the connection. In my case, I'm using the client and can confirm that I'm not doing anything that would break the connection (at least not on purpose) -- the browser remains open, etc., when this error occurs.

Any idea what might be causing this (and how to fix)?

```
public class GetFile extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
  super.init(config);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
  throws ServletException, IOException {

String filename ="init_java";

try {

    // get user parameters
    filename = req.getParameter("fileId");  // complete path to video file
    //res.setContentType("video/mp4");  //not working
    res.setContentType("application/x-download");  

    File file=new File(filename);

    if (file.exists()) {

        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""+filename+"\"");
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "cache, must-revalidate");
        //res.setHeader("Pragma", "public"); // not sure when to use
        returnFile(filename, res.getOutputStream());

    } else {
        //error handling goes here
    }     

} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
} finally {
    ... 
}
}


private static void returnFile(String filename, OutputStream out) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  InputStream in = null;
  try {
      in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
      byte[] buf = new byte[4 * 1024]; // 4K buffer
      int bytesRead;
      while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
          out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
      }

  } finally {
      if (in != null) in.close();
  }
}

}
```

***UPDATE 1***

I'm seeing the following error in the `mod_jk.log` file (which transfers the request from Apache web server to GlassFish application server):

```
[info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3383): mod_jk/1.2.40 initialized
[error] ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1313): wrong message format 0xcad5 from ::1:8009
[error] ajp_get_reply::jk_ajp_common.c (2204): (worker1) Tomcat is down or network problems. Part of the response has already been sent to the client
[info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (worker1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of protocol error (attempt=1)
[info] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (2000): Writing to client aborted or client network problems
[info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (worker1) sending request to tomcat failed (unrecoverable), because of client write error (attempt=2)
[info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2799): Aborting connection for worker=worker1
```

It appears to be tracking what I observe, but I'm not an expert here -- does this offer any insight into what might be the root cause?

Comment: Try `.flush()` the output stream after everything has been written to it.

Comment: Thanks @FabianBarney, I added `out.flush();` after the while loop in `returnFile()` but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: It might an infrastructure issue - e.g. a firewall/router which drops the connection of some kind and duration.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki, I download files larger than 4 MB for software updates all the time, so I don't think it's my client infrastructure limiting this. It should be something on the server. I checked the server firewall and confirmed that won't limit it. What else could it be?

Comment: @user46688 - for sure I don't follow your infrastructure set up, but the obstacle might be between your client and server. As far as I *guess* downloading software updates happens elsewhere (not between these two).   Anyway, I am just guessing blindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a GlassFish bug. Fix is to install 2 files found here:

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18446

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a limitation set on you server. Check the properties file. I am sure there is one that says no files larger than 2MB.

Comment: Thanks @andreipuf, could you be more specific regarding the term "server"? For example, do you mean Apache web server, or something else? Can the file size be increased in an .htaccess file, etc.?

Comment: For Apache the file is php.ini. For tomcat I know that the input/output buffer is set to 2048 bytes. You can see that in web.xml file. I am not sure if it is possible to increase it globally for tomcat as can be done for Apache.

Comment: thanks @andreipuf, I'm not using php, so I suppose that file won't apply here. I'm using GlassFish, and I'll check if there's any limits set for it. thanks